# Mysql actual and running average temperature query

Tags: mysql, d3.js

Temperatures of my solar hot water jacket are recorded in about every 3 minutes in a table called `boiler`:

```
id - date - time - lowT - higT
```

e.g.

```
1 - 2016-12-06 - 00:41:26 - 37.69 - 23.38
```

Data gaps may occur due to poor internet connection, power failure or other problems.

For presentation in d3 I need flowing selection:

```
time - lowTtd - higTyd - higTtd - higTyd - lowTav - higTav

where

time is the table.time in 3 minute steps e.g. 00:03:00, 00:06:00 ....

lowTtd is the table.lowT from today, but empty if Now() < time

lowTyd is the table.lowT from yesterday, but empty if Now() > time
```

lowTav is running avg +-30 minutes of table.lowT since recording started

hig... respectively the same as for low...

To achieve this I have another table with time-steps called intervaller:

```
start

00:00:00
00:03:00
00:06:00
.
.
23:57:00
```

Currently I use following code:

```
SELECT xx.start 
AS date, xx.lowTtd, xx.lowTyd, xx.higTtd, xx.higTyd, yy.lowTav, yy.higTav 
FROM (SELECT i.start,
time AS date, (CASE WHEN time<DATE_ADD(NOW(), 
INTERVAL -1 HOUR) THEN lowT ELSE '' END) AS lowTtd, (CASE WHEN time>DATE_ADD(NOW(), 
INTERVAL -1 HOUR) THEN lowT ELSE '' END) AS lowTyd, (CASE WHEN time<DATE_ADD(NOW(), 
INTERVAL -1 HOUR) THEN higT ELSE '' END) AS higTtd, (CASE WHEN time>DATE_ADD(NOW(), 
INTERVAL -1 HOUR) THEN higT ELSE '' END) AS higTyd 
FROM boiler, intervaler i 
WHERE HOUR(TIMEDIFF(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR), concat(date,' ',time)))<24 
AND time > i.start 
AND time < DATE_ADD(i.start, INTERVAL 3 MINUTE) 
GROUP BY i.start 
ORDER BY `time` ASC) xx, 
(SELECT i.start, AVG(b.lowT) AS lowTav, AVG(b.higT) AS higTav 
FROM intervaler i, `boiler` b 
WHERE b.time > DATE_ADD(i.start, INTERVAL -30 MINUTE) AND b.time < DATE_ADD(i.start, INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) 
GROUP BY i.start) yy WHERE xx.start = yy.start
```

It works, however, I am sure that there is great room for improvement especially in regard to query time. 'boiler' contains less than 5500 entries, but my query takes almost 1s.

Would appreciate highly any suggestion how to improve my code.

Thank you and best regards.

[example of d3 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6mxo.png)